# node.js socket.io cannot send to specific client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I found a few references to this but nothing that actually direct helps. Also according to some research this is the proper way to send a message to a specific client. I have:

```
io.sockets.socket(players[i].id).emit('deal_card', {
    // etc
});
```

and I get this error on that line:

```
Missing error handler on 'socket'.TypeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method 'socket'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For socket.io 1.0 use:

```
io.sockets.connected[players[i].id].emit('deal_card', {..});
```

For 0.9 use:

```
io.sockets.sockets[players[i].id].emit('deal_card', {..});
```

(not io.sockets.socket[players[i].id].emit('deal_card', {..});)